# limit set of infinite subsequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Assume we divide a sequence into infinite number of sub-sequences and consider the set of limits of those sub-sequences. Will that set of limits cover the set of partial limits of mother sequence?

How to prove that it will not cover?

Comment: Consider an enumeration of the rationals. (I assume you split into convergent subsequences.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider the sequence

$$\sigma=\langle \color{red}1,\color{blue}{1,2},\color{red}{1,2,3},\color{blue}{1,2,3,4},\color{red}{1,2,3,4,5},\ldots\rangle\;,$$

where the colors are merely to emphasize the construction of the sequence. The limits of convergent subsequences of $\sigma$ are precisely the positive integers. However, we can split $\sigma$ into the convergent subsequences

$$\begin{align*}
&\langle 1,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots\rangle\;,\\
&\langle 1,3,3,3,3,3,\ldots\rangle\;,\\
&\langle 1,4,4,4,4,4,\ldots\rangle\;,
\end{align*}$$

and so on, whose limits are the integers greater than $1$: none of them has limit $1$, though $\sigma$ has $1$ as a subsequential limit.

We can go even further by splitting it into the subsequences

$$\begin{align*}
&\langle 1,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots\rangle\;,\\
&\langle 1,3,4,4,4,4,4,\ldots\rangle\;,\\
&\langle 1,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,\ldots\rangle\;,
\end{align*}$$

and so on: now the limits are the even positive integers, so we’ve lost infinitely many of the subsequential limits of $\sigma$.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TaguhiMesropyan: You’re very welcome.